# VueJS Passing object in props

Tags: vue.js, ref, prop

I am building controllers for sets of items. I am currently create a Javascript object, complete with functions and storing it in the data of the Vue instance. I am then passing this object like: `<dynamic-table :table-object="objTable"></dynamic-table>`

I am wondering if this is passed by reference or is it making a deep copy of the object every time the view is rendered.

I know VueEx might be a better solution but I am not able to use NodeJS for this project.

Comment: Vuex doesn't need Node.js. Where'd you get that idea? Use the "direct download" version on https://vuex.vuejs.org/en/installation.html.

Comment: ahh good to know (y), but initial question still stands.

Answer (score 2):

The object is passed by reference. You can make a deep copy of the object inside the `<dynamic-table>`-component as follows:

```
data() {
    return {
      tableObject: JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.tableObj)),
    };
},
```

Comment: Perfect, I was worried that doing things this way might have a horrible unseen complexity.